# How to determine the network hash rate of last 12 hours?

Tags: hashrate

I want to determine the network hashrate as etherscan.io shows.

As I know,difficulty is the times of hashing to find the next block.

So, the sum of difficulty should be the times of hashing in last 12 hours.

So I think this way should be right:

1. Sum the difficulty of the last 12 hours
2. Div the sum by seconds of 12hours (43200)

It show me that the hash rate should be 219,446 GH/s

But etherscan.io show me that hash rate is 262,744.29 GH/s

What is the difference?

Comment: Might be that you're not including the difficulty of any uncle blocks?

Comment: got it , you are right